# i am creating a ecommerce website and i want to display size variant of perticular product

Tags: python, html, django

my models.py

```
class SizeVariant(models.Model):
    size_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.size_name
    

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True,blank=True)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    price=models.IntegerField()
    desc=models.TextField()
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='products')
    color_variant=models.ManyToManyField(ColorVariant, blank=True)
    size_variant=models.ManyToManyField(SizeVariant, blank=True)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug=slugify(self.product_name)
        super(Product,self).save(*args,kwargs)
```

my html template

```
                               <div class="product__details__option__size">
                                    <span>Size:</span>
                                    {% for size in product.size_variant.all %}  
                                        <label for="{{size.size_name}}">{{size.size_name}}
                                            <input type="radio" >
                                        </label>
                                    {% endfor %} 
                                </div>
```

i have tried using for loop to show all the size variant of particular  product but its not working

i think there is problem in for loop. because its not taking size variant from database

Comment: How did you pass the `product` to the template? Can you share the view that does the template rendering?

Comment: def get_product(request,slug):
    try:
        product=Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
        
        context={
            'product':product
        }
        return render(request, 'shop-detail.html', context)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)